# How to view pg_dump data with .sql extension?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have downloaded pg_dump data from [DeepDive Open Datasets](http://deepdive.stanford.edu/opendata/#plos-public-library-of-science). It is a file with extension .sql and to my knowledge that is a text file with SQL commands in it to recreate the database. I'm trying to peruse the data. How do I set up a Postgres database to do that?

I tried to use pgAdmin4 to view the data. However, I'm not sure how to set up and add a new server to read the data. I'm not sure if that is the correct approach.

I would appreciate any guidance with this.

Answer (score 1):

You would view the dump itself with a pager like `more` or `less`; such a dump is a plain text file with SQL statements.

To restore such a dump you need to use `psql`, the command line client:

```sh
psql -U postgres -d adatabase -f dumpfile.sql
```

pgAdmin cannot restore such a dump, because it contains `COPY ... FROM STDIN` statements intermixed with the data.

Comment: I get `psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`
I have also run `initdb -U postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data`

Comment: If your superuser is not called `postgres`, use the appropriate name instead. But if the database cluster was created with the `initdb` you quote, the superuser would be called `postgres`, so it is obvious that your running cluster was not created with that `initdb` statement. Looks like you messed something up.